# Como contar empleados a cargo en MySQL?

Tags: sql, count

le he estado dando vueltas a este problema:

tengo esta tabla empleados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que por cada empleado me haga un conteo de cuantas personas estan por debajo de su nivel jerárquico, siendo Fredi el lider de los niveles (si imaginamos un organigrama).

Las respuestas deberian ser

Fredi = 4

Mafi = 2

Diego = 2

Sofi = 1

Tomy = 0

---

La verdad que intenté de varias maneras, busqué mucho en la web, pero no pude definirla, hasta le consulté a 3 profesionales pero tampoco pudieron darme respuesta.

De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: Para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar es necesario agregues que has intentado, aún cuando esos intentos pues no resultaran

Comment: Primero, esta tabla está mal hecha, ya que tiene redundancia de datos, lo cual puede producir inconsistencias. ¿Para qué poner el nombre del manager si ya tienes el id? Dicho esto, la respuesta que muestras no se condice con la tabla, ya que Diego no tiene a nadie por debajo. Y volviendo a tu respuesta, creo que tienes que hacer joins recursivos, y para esto necesitas usar una CTE (common table expression).

Comment: [Hierarchical Recursive Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/1423096) para buscar info en la web proba esta frase https://www.google.com/search?q=hierarchical+data+in+mysql  y/o en el [dev](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-three-hierarchies/)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por sus respuestas, seguí buscando y me topé con una respuesta que me funcionó, aunque sinceramente no pude interpretar todas las líneas, pero bueno, si alguien busca este problema puede servirle

```sql
    SELECT nombre, (  
    select max(cnt)
      from (
       select @ids:=(
                 select group_concat(id)
                   from empleados
                  where find_in_set(id_manager,@ids)>0
              ),
              @cnt:=@cnt+(select count(1)
                            from empleados
                           where find_in_set(id,@ids)>0) as cnt
         from empleados E,
              (select @cnt:=0,@ids:=id) X  -- <--- @ids is starting ID for search 
        limit 3 -- <-- set limit to maximal Tree nesting level or more
      ) X
      ) as REPORTES
      FROM empleados
      order by REPORTES DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dejando de lado el hecho que debes revisar el diseño de la tabla. Sería algo así:

```sql
SELECT
    nombre_manager, -- Mostrar el nombre del supervisor
    COUNT(*) AS colaboradores -- Contar los agrupados
FROM
    empleados
WHERE
    id_manager IS NOT NULL -- Solo los registros de empleados supervisados
GROUP BY
    id_manager, nombre_manager -- Agrupados por el manager
```

Propuesta:

```sql
-- DDL
CREATE TABLE empleados (
  id INT DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_manager INT DEFAULT NULL
)

-- DML
SELECT
    m.nombre, -- Mostrar el nombre del supervisor
    COUNT(*) AS colaboradores -- Contar los agrupados
FROM
    empleados m
INNER JOIN 
    empleados c
ON
    m.id = c.id_manager 
WHERE
    c.id_manager IS NOT NULL -- Solo los registros de empleados supervisados
GROUP BY
    c.id_manager, m.nombre -- Agrupados por el manager
```

Comment: Bien, gracias, lo que intenté fue crear una vista con el nivel de cada uno, y después quise hacer un conteo por fila de id empleado cuyo nivel sea mayor (siendo fredy el 1) que su propio nivel.

Comment: Agregue una propuesta para que remuevas la redundancia, ya que como te comento @andrew. Si ya tienes el id_manager entonces el nombre_manager sobra.

Comment: Creo que no es lo que necesita, porque pide toda la jerarquía completa, no sólo un nivel. Además, el `WHERE` no es necesario ya que nunca habíra `JOIN` si fuera `NULL`.